# Converting multiple csv. files into multiple matrixs with original names in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix, naming

I have 20 csv. files with data.frames and wanna convert one of the columns (logF0) in each dataframe into a 20*16 matrix. The result should be 20 20*16 matrixs and I hope the names of the matrix could be the same as the csv. files. I thought I could use a loop to convert the dataframe separately to matrix at first:

```
files_list<-list.files("my_path", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.csv") 
for(i in 1: length(files_list))
{dat<-data.frame()
  mat<-matrix()
  file[i]<-rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
  mat[i]<-rbind(mat, matrix(file[i]$logF0, nrow=20, byrow = F))}
```

It doesn't work, I feel like the naming of `file[i]` and `mat[i]` have some problems but I don't know how to fix it, and I couldn't figure out how to name the matrix as it originally is in csv. files.

Comment: `mylist <- sapply(files_list, read.csv, simplify = FALSE)` is a start, with a named-list (name is the filename) of matrices. From there, you can do something like `do.call(rbind, mylist)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
all_data <- lapply(files_list, function(file) {
   df <- read.csv(file)
   matrix(df$$logF0, nrow = 20)
})
```

If you want to give this list names, you could do :

```
names(all_data) <- sub('\\.csv', '', basename(file_list))
```